# Automating my Makefile

Tags: c++, c, makefile, g++

I am learning to create a makefile. My folder structure looks like this..

> Project
>
> ```
>     bin        //this is where the executable "e" is kept
>           e
>     obj        //this is where the obj files generated are kept
>           Node.o
>           Node1.o
>     src        //this is where .cpp files resides
>           Folder
>                    Node.cpp
>           Folder2
>                    Node1.cpp
>     include    //this is where .hhp files resides
>           Folder
>                    Node.hpp
>           Folder2
>                    Node1.hpp
>     makefile
> ```

I am using Ubuntu 12.04 and trying to compile it using g++. The makefile resides in the project folder along with folders: src, include, obj and bin

My makefile looks like this

```
CC = g++
DEBUG = -g
CFLAGS = -Wall -c $(DEBUG)
LFLAGS = -Wall $(DEBUG)
TARGET = bin/
OBJ = obj/
INCLUDE = include/
SRC = src/

SOURCES=$(wildcard $(SRC)**/*.cpp $(SRC)*.cpp)
HEADERS=$(wildcard include/**/*.hpp include/*.hpp)
OBJECTS=$(patsubst %.cpp,$(OBJ)%.o,$(notdir $(SOURCES)))

All : $(TARGET)e

$(TARGET)e : make_dir $(OBJECTS)
    $(CC) $(LFLAGS) $(OBJECTS) -o $@

$(OBJ)Node.o : $(SRC)Folder/Node.cpp $(HEADERS)      
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -I$(INCLUDE) $< -o $@
$(OBJ)Node1.o : $(SRC)Folder2/Node1.cpp $(HEADERS)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -I$(INCLUDE) $< -o $@

make_dir:
    mkdir -p obj bin
clean :
    -rm -rf bin
    -rm -rf obj 
    -rm -f e *.o *~
```

This piece of code runs just fine but what I would like to do is to replace the below code snippets

```
$(OBJ)Node.o : $(SRC)Folder/Node.cpp $(HEADERS)      
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -I$(INCLUDE) $< -o $@
$(OBJ)Node1.o : $(SRC)Folder2/Node1.cpp $(HEADERS)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -I$(INCLUDE) $< -o $@
```

with some thing more like

```
%.o : %.cpp $(HEADERS)      
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -I$(INCLUDE) $< -o $@
```

Something that generalizes the whole feeding and mapping. In other words, automate the makefile in a way I shouldn't worry or edit until the hierarchy is disturbed.

Comment: This link might help you http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html

Answer (score 1):

```
$(OBJ)/%.o : $(SRC)Folder/%.cpp $(HEADERS)      
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -I$(INCLUDE) $< -o $@
```

Comment: But as you can see the I have different folders in src/ for example folder1, folder2, folder3 etc inside which the cpp files exist. What can be done in that case?